# anybody have an unsetup.bash?

Tags: ros, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would like to run the opposite of source devel/setup.bash, i.e., unsetup.bash.  Has anyone coded this up already?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245421/anybody-have-an-unsetup.bash?/) by [rosnutsbolts](https://answers.ros.org/users/28002/rosnutsbolts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no but yes.

If you don't want the environment changes that ROS makes at all, I'd advise that you open a new terminal without sourcing setup.bash

Running the setup.bash from another workspace will unset the changes made by the previous setup.bash. If you really want it you may be able to extract the unset behavior from the setup scripts, but it is fairly complicated

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1